# Using try catch to handle an object who attribute doesn't exist

Tags: python, exception

So my function goes something like this,

```
  def something(self,student,x,y):

      ....
      ....

      try:
         tmp=student['id']
      except KeyError:
         tmp=student['student_id']
```

This function can be called by multiple functions and when a call is made where student object only contains meta-data "student_id", the function fails at the line "tmp=student['id']" with the error "General Exception: student object has no attribute 'id'"

As a workaround I added a few flags to understand from where the call is being made and handle the meta-data  appropriately.

```
  def something(self,student,x,y,flag=False):

      ....
      ....

      if flag:
         tmp=student['id']
      else:
         tmp=student['student_id']
```

My question is can't this be done without introducing the extra parameter "flag" and preferably with try-catch itself ?

More information :

Suppose the call is made from func1

```
  def func1(self,a,b):

      self.something(student,x,y,True) #'id' would be used

  def func2(self,a,b):

      self.something(student,x,y,False) #'student_id' should be used
```

When the call is made from func2, only 'student_id' meta-data is present, that's why I want to know if this can be achieved by exception handling

Comment: If you know already which it's going to be, why not make the key a parameter, defaulting to `'id'`: `def something(self, x, y, key='id'):`.

Comment: How are you ending up with the different exception? What is `student`?

Comment: The other functions which call this function cannot pass a "key" each time they call it

Comment: @pvg - student is a parameter of the function, edited the question to include it

Comment: It's still not really clear what you're trying to accomplish. Why not just check for the presence of whatever keys? Using exceptions for this is both slow and needlessly convoluted.

Comment: Also i meant what sort of object is student. Is it a collection? A class of some sort?

Comment: A list . student = [ {'id': 12 , 'name' : 'something'}] but if called from func2, its nature is different, then student contains , student=[{'student_id':12,'name':'something}]

Comment: That looks like a dict inside a list, not a list and it doesn't match the code you've shown. Add this info to your question, accurately

Answer (score 0):

Never use try/catch to check if some value is in dictionary/object. For dictionaries do something like:

```
if "id" in student:
    # your code here
elif "student_id" in student:
    # your code here
else:
    # probably error
```

if you have object like structure, then use builtin functions [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#hasattr) and [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the `get` method of the dictionary. It takes a second argument which it will return if the key doesn't exist.

```
student.get('id', student['student_id'])
```